# how to select in 3 table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created 3 table

table 1 "Sale" that saved date of user sale
table 2 "ProductFactor" that saved factorid and productid in wich factoreid
tabel 3 "Product" that saved productid and product name

I want select in 3 table for this result:

show user factorid +price+ saledate + any product name that avalibe in this factorid

but when do it, for example when in one factorid that have 3 productid, is show this:

```
    
    date                 factoreid              name              price 
    2013-09-25 1          1                       a               2000
    2013-09-25 1          1                       b               3000
    2013-09-25 2          2                       c               4000
    2013-09-25 3          3                       d               3500
    2013-09-25 1          1                       e               8000
```

I want show this:

```
    
    date                 factoreid              name                price                   sumprice 
    2013-09-25 1          1                      a,b,e      a price,b price, c price    sum of this 3 product name
    2013-09-25 2          2                       c                 4000
    2013-09-25 3          3                       d                 3500 my code is:
```

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUserSaleReport] 
    @CurrentUserId uniqueidentifier 
AS BEGIN 

SELECT      dbo.Sale.SaleDate,
            dbo.ProductFactor.FactoreId,
            dbo.Product.ProductName,
            dbo.Product.Price
FROM        Sale 

INNER JOIN  ProductFactor 
    ON      dbo.Sale.FactoreId=dbo.ProductFactor.FactoreId  

INNER JOIN dbo.Product
    ON     dbo.ProductFactor.ProductId=dbo.Product.ProductId  

WHERE      dbo.Sale.UserId = @CurrentUserId 
    AND    dbo.Sale.FactoreId=dbo.ProductFactor.FactoreId
    AND    dbo.ProductFactor.ProductId=dbo.Product.ProductId  

ORDER BY   dbo.Sale.SaleDate 

END
```

Comment: i do not have time to provide a complete answer but you need to look into the 'For XML' mehtod

Comment: You should set up a SQL Fiddle. I'm close to a solution, but it's hard to test without the table structures and I'm not motivated enough this early in the morning to manually create it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have all three tables but assuming all this data was coming from one table you could do something like this... You can apply the same login after you have joined all the tables and have got all the required data in one place

```
SELECT DISTINCT  [DATE], Factoreid, STUFF(T2.NameList, 1, 2, '') AS name, STUFF(T3.PriceList, 1, 2, '') AS price, SUM(Price) PriceSUM
    FROM TableName t 
                OUTER APPLY (
                            SELECT ', ' + name [text()]
                            FROM TableName 
                            WHERE Factoreid = t.Factoreid
                            FOR XML PATH('')
                            ) T2(NameList)
                OUTER APPLY (
                            SELECT  ', ' + CAST(price AS VARCHAR) [text()]
                            FROM TableName 
                            WHERE Factoreid = t.Factoreid
                            FOR XML PATH('')
                            ) T3(PriceList)
    GROUP BY [DATE], Factoreid, STUFF(T2.NameList, 1, 2, ''), STUFF(T3.PriceList, 1, 2, '')
```

I have tried tweaked the code I think it will work try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUserSaleReport] 
@CurrentUserId uniqueidentifier 
AS BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temptable') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Temptable    

SELECT      dbo.Sale.SaleDate           AS [DATE],
            dbo.ProductFactor.FactoreId AS Factoreid,
            dbo.Product.ProductName     AS Name,
            dbo.Product.Price           AS Price
        INTO #Temptable
FROM        Sale 

INNER JOIN  ProductFactor 
    ON      dbo.Sale.FactoreId=dbo.ProductFactor.FactoreId  

INNER JOIN dbo.Product
    ON     dbo.ProductFactor.ProductId=dbo.Product.ProductId  

WHERE      dbo.Sale.UserId = @CurrentUserId 
    AND    dbo.Sale.FactoreId=dbo.ProductFactor.FactoreId
    AND    dbo.ProductFactor.ProductId=dbo.Product.ProductId  

ORDER BY   dbo.Sale.SaleDate 

SELECT DISTINCT  [DATE], Factoreid, STUFF(T2.NameList, 1, 2, '') AS name, STUFF(T3.PriceList, 1, 2, '') AS price, SUM(Price) PriceSUM
FROM #Temptable t 
            OUTER APPLY (
                        SELECT ', ' + Name [text()]
                        FROM #Temptable 
                        WHERE Factoreid = t.Factoreid
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        ) T2(NameList)
                OUTER APPLY (
                            SELECT  ', ' + CAST(price AS VARCHAR) [text()]
                            FROM #Temptable 
                            WHERE Factoreid = t.Factoreid
                            FOR XML PATH('')
                            ) T3(PriceList)
GROUP BY [DATE], Factoreid, STUFF(T2.NameList, 1, 2, ''), STUFF(T3.PriceList, 1, 2, '')

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temptable') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Temptable   

  SET NOCOUNT OFF;

END
```